# How to put a break line in string?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, visual-c++

How can i put break line in string.
Something like this.

```
string var = "hey
s";
```

Would be something like this.

```
hey
s
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just put a `\n` between `hey` and `s`. So:

```
string var = "hey\ns";
```

Answer (score 2):

Line breaking can be achieved using Dan's advice:

```
string var = "hey\ns";
```

Note that you cannot do this the way you wanted:

```
string var = "hey     // this is not
s";                   // valid code
```

and it's a design choice of C++.

Older languages generally do not allow you to define multiline strings.

But, for example, Python does allow you exactly this:

```
someString = """
    this is a
    multiline
    string
"""
```

and printing `someString` will give you a true multiline string.

You can forget about this when using C++, though.

Answer (score 2):

A line break is encoded as the char `'\n'`. So just write `\n` into your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
string var =
"\
some text\n\
some more text\n\
and even more text\
";
```

and var would be equels to

```
some text
some more text
and even more text
```

Answer (score -4):

you should try this
string var = "hey"."/n"."s";

Comment: That wouldn't work, for a start I don't believe you can concatenate strings in C++ with a ".", that's a PHP thing (probably as well as other languages). Also, the /n should be a \n ([backslash]n).